# How to route to a static folder and serve html contents within that folder ?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am beginner in laravel & trying to serve html contents through route. the contents are about api documentation so i want to serve it through route. the documetation contains in /doc with following directory structure.

```
/laravel_project
  .
  .
  doc/
   .
   .
   index.html
```

i want to serve this contents on following route:

```
Route::get('/apiDoc', function () {

    return File::get(public_path() . '/doc/index.html');

});
```

I tried like above but it is not working. please help me with same how can i serve this contents

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your static folder under views folder:

```
/laravel_project
 - Resources
  - Views
   - Doc
    - index.html
```

Create a controller method like following:

```
public function index($slug = null)
{
    if ($slug == null)
        abort(404);

    $viewTarget = 'doc.' . $slug;

    if (view()->exists( $viewTarget )) {
        return view( $viewTarget );
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }

    return view('home');
}
```

Now you can create a route for this method:

```
Route::get('docs/{urlSlug}', 'YourController@index');
```

Now you can access the url like: `project.url/docs/fileName` (You don't need to add file extension)

Comment: What is the issue?